# Make 2D images in scene with 3D objects unaffected by light in Three.js and React.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphics, three.js, lighting

I'm trying to make a scene that has a 2D image and a 3D image using Three.js and React.js. When the 2D image is clicked, it turns the 3D image to wireframe mode. However, the lighting in the scene is making the 2D image extremely bright to the point where it's almost all just white. Any suggestions on how to fix this issue?

From what I understand, having 2 different scenes doesn't work because in order for the click event to work they have to be in the same scene.

Is there an easier way to add an image button on top of the scene that interacts with the 3D components in the scene?

When lighting is dimmed the image is more visible:
[image]

Under the desired lighting for the rest of scene the image is too bright: 
[image]

Comment: If you want a surface unaffected by light, it's best to choose the unlit material [MeshBasicMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/materials/MeshBasicMaterial).

Comment: @Mugen87 Just what I was looking for thank you!